# What is the defininition of phase Space in simple terms?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, systems-of-equations

I’m currently studying a Differential Equations Course, and I’m focusing on a chapter called “Systems of ODE”, the text gives a definition of phase space, but I can’t seem to visualise or understand what it is graphically. Could someone break it down?

Here is the definition of phase space I’ve been given:

> For an autonomous $N$-th order ODE system $dx/dt = f(x)$, $x$, $f \in \mathbb R^N$, the phase space is $\text{dom }(f) \subset \mathbb R^N$, that is, the sub-set of the $N$-dimensional space, where the right-hand sides of the system are defined.

Thank you

Comment: It is simply the domain of the function f.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it has been presented by you, the phase space $D$ is the domain of $f$. Usually is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$.

I interpret it in the following way. Every point in $D$ is a **state** of a dynamical system. Suppose you want to study a simulation of a physical process. You select $N$ variables to be tracked during the simulation and all the possible combinations of admisible values constitute the set of all states: the phase space $D$.

Then you have to write down a **dynamical law** for this system, which says how the variables change with time: this is the function $f$ in your question. It is an "arrow" in every point of the phase space (state) that tells you in which direction are you moving from this state when times goes on.

**Example:**

Imagine two variables $R,F$ depending on time, representing the amount of rabbits and foxes in a forest. All the possible combinations of values constitute the phase space, in this case
$$
D=\{(x,y)\in R^2:x\geq 0,y\geq 0\}
$$
You can consider a dynamical law (the [Lotka-Volterra equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations), for example) that tells you how the system change.

I want to put an image but the server is down. Here you are [a link](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PredatorPreyModel/).

Comment: Thank You, that makes sense now